# Incorrect Passbook file

Tags: ios, icloud, passbook

I generate Passbook's files (.pkpass) with [this library](https://github.com/tschoffelen/PHP-PKPass).
On my Mac, the generated file opens correctly.
But when I click on "Add to Passbook" the file is not added on my iPhone. And when I send the file by e-mail on my iPhone, his name is "(null)" and I can't open it.
Why my pkpass file is incorrect ?

Comment: Mac Passbook preview doesn't validate the everything in .pkpass file. You can drag the pkpass file to iPhone Simulator and check the log in the Console app for error details. Or if you can provide a link to your pkpass file or the pass.json so we can take a look and advise

Comment: When I try to download .pkpass with Safari the console display : Invalid data error reading pass pass.com.PASS_ID/SERIAL_NUMBER. The passTypeIdentifier or teamIdentifier provided may not match your certificate, or the certificate trust chain could not be verified.

Comment: Have you created your Pass Type ID and set it as described in README.md  of the [PHP PKPass](https://github.com/tschoffelen/PHP-PKPass) library you are using? ie. 

Step 4: Change the `passTypeIdentifier` and `teamIndentifier` to the correct values, which can be found on the iOS Provisioning portal after clicking on 'Configure' next to the Pass ID, on line 15 and 17

Comment: My `passTypeIdentifier` and `teamIndentifier` are correct. How to know if the problem is AppleWWDRCA.pem or my certificate (.p12) ?

Comment: Ok, I don't make mistakes. According to [these feedback](https://github.com/tschoffelen/PHP-PKPass/issues/41) this library is not compatible with iOS 7. I downloaded iOS 6 for iOS Simulator and my pass displayed correctly, not in iOS 7.